Rails many-to-many association query by AND of associated records
I have a Rails project with a Product model and a Feature model and a many-to-many relationship between them as follows:
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: products
#
#  id                                   :bigint           not null, primary key
#  created_at                           :datetime         not null
#  updated_at                           :datetime         not null
#
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :product_features, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :features, through: :product_features
end

# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: features
#
#  id                                   :bigint           not null, primary key
#  created_at                           :datetime         not null
#  updated_at                           :datetime         not null
#
class Feature < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :product_features, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :products, through: :product_features
end

# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: product_features
#
#  id            :bigint           not null, primary key
#  created_at    :datetime         not null
#  updated_at    :datetime         not null
#  product_id    :bigint           not null
#  feature_id    :bigint           not null
#
# Indexes
#
#  index_product_features_on_product_id  (product_id)
#  index_product_features_on_feature_id  (feature_id)
#
# Foreign Keys
#
#  fk_rails_...  (product_id => products.id)
#  fk_rails_...  (feature_id => features.id)
#
class ProductFeature < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :feature
end

I want to have a filter on the products that returns the products that have all of a list of features.
For example:
Product 1 has Feature 1, Feature 2 and Feature 3.
Product 2 has Feature 2, Feature 3 and Feature 4.
Product 3 has Feature 3, Feature 4 and Feature 5.
Product 4 has Feature 2 and Feature 5.
If the filter is given Feature 2 and Feature 3, it should return Product 1 and Product 2 but not Product 3 or Product 4.
The best that I've come up with so far is the following:
def filter_by_features(feature_ids_array)
  product_id_arrays = []
  feature_ids_array.each do |feature_id|
    product_id_arrays << ProductFeature.where(feature_id: feature_id).pluck(:product_id)
  end
  Product.where(id: product_id_arrays.inject(:&))
end

I'm not fond of this solution because it results in N+1 queries. How can I refactor the filter to get rid of the N+1 queries?
The project is on Rails 6.0 and PostGres 12.

You most never need or want to pluck ids and pass them around. It's  ineffecient. Instead use .select(:product_id) and pass the ActiveRecord relation. This lets AR construct a subquery so you avoid both the round trip to the database and the memory usage.

You can use a combination of joins and having to accomplish what you need.
Product.joins(:product_features)
       .where(product_features: { feature_id: feature_ids_array })
       .group('products.id')
       .having('count(*) = ?', feature_ids_array.length)

For this to work properly, it is important to guarantee uniqueness of the product_id and feature_id combination in the ProductFeature model. This is best done on the database level by adding a unique index there:
add_index :product_features, [:product_id, :feature_id], unique: true


Probably join with product_features is enough, don't need features Product.joins(:product_features).where(product_features: { feature_id: feature_ids_array }).group('products.id').having('count(*) = ?', feature_ids_array.length)

Works perfectly. Thanks for the tip about the index. I should have added that regardless of what filters I implemented.

You can avoid the SQL strings with group(:id) and having(ProductFeature.arel_table[Arel.star].eq(feature_ids_array.length)).
